# Is there a speed difference between the mounts?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

As answered on [Which Machines can I mount?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/301881/which-machines-can-i-mount), you can mount one of three machines.

> 1. Striders
> 2. Broadheads
> 3. Chargers

While you can get different mounts, I have not noticed much of a speed difference between them. Does each mount get their own riding speed, or is your mount choice more of a cosmetic opinion?

Comment: If there is, I've certainly not noticed it.

Comment: I've only rode Striders and Broadheads so far, and as David mentioned, if there is, I haven't noticed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having completed the game, and from doing some light testing with each mount, I can safely say that no, there is no speed difference between mounts.

I tested by taking each mount in a straight line from the campfire at Sunfall to the campfire slightly South-East of Sunfall. Times were relatively the same, save for small nuances when the mounts slowed themselves and I needed to press X again to get them to gallop.